# Decompose table into third normal form

Tags: database-design, normalization, dependencies

Tables X and Y are given as below :

```
X (A, B, D, E, F, G, H, J) with A and B as primary key
Y (K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R) with K and L as primary key
```

Now we need to decompose these tables into tables in the third normal form using the functional dependencies specified below:

1. A   ->  G, H
2. B   ->  D, E, F
3. E   ->  F
4. H   ->  G
5. L   ->  N, O, P, Q
6. N   ->  Q

I need to specify primary keys and foreign keys also. Please help to solve this problem.

I am newbie to normalization. So please help to solve this problem.If I normalize to 2NF I loose some relations which doesn't suit to 3NF. So I am confused. Any help will be appreciated. Because to convert to 3NF I need to go through 2NF too.

I had changed it to 3NF. Please help in finding if am right in doing it

```
R1 (E, F)
R2 (H, G)
R3 (A, B, L)
R4 (A, H)
R5 (B, D, E)

R6 (N, Q)
R7 (K, L, M, R)
R8 (L, N, O, P)
```

Comment: Should be `R3 (A,B,J)`. And `R7 (K,L,M,R)`. Otherwise, I think you have it all right! Also specify which is the primary key in each relation (R1 has E, R2 has H, R3 has (A,B), etc.)

Comment: @ypercube Please can you tell me primary keys and foreign keys for tables R1 to R8 ?

Comment: @ypercube I edited the tables after normalisation. But am not sure of foreign and primary keys

Comment: Hi @user119249 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We have

```
X (A, B, D, E, F, G, H, J) with A and B as primary key
Y (K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R) with K and L as primary key
```

With functional dependencies:

```
A -> G, H
B -> D, E, F
E -> F
H -> G
L -> N, O, P, Q
N -> Q
```

### 2NF Normalization

```
R1((A,B) (PK), J)
R2(A (PK) ,G,H)
R3(B (PK) ,D,E,F)
R4((K,L) (PK), M,R)
R5(L (PK) ,N,O,P,Q)
```

### 3NF Normalization

```
Ra((A,B) (PK), J)
Rb(A (PK) ,H)
Rc(H(PK), G)
Rd(B(PK),D,E)
Re(E(PK),F)
Rf((K,L) (PK), M,R)
Rg(L (PK),N,O,P)
Rh(N (PK), Q)
```